# Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. Line 26 Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function sendMail() {
  var ofo = 1;
  var restaurant = 2;
  var name = 3;
  var email = 4;
  var sent = 5;

  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Email");

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invalid Login MM Pull Internal");

  var data = ws.getRange("A2:F" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

  data.forEach(function(row){

    emailTemp.ofo = row[ofo];
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Guide to Resetting Online Delivery Passwords.pdf");
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    var startRow = 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
    if (row[sent] !== "EMAIL_SENT"){
        GmailApp.sendEmail(row[email], "Otter Onboarding: Invalid " + row[ofo] + " Logins Submitted", 
        "Your email doesn't support HTML, please trying using another browser.",
        {name: "The Otter Onboarding team", 
        htmlBody: htmlMessage, replyTo: "onboarding@tryotter.com",
        attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
        });
        ws.getRange(2 + i,6).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
      };
    };
     });
}
```

**I am trying to attached this PDF to my emails but it keep saying line 26 there is an error: Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.**

Comment: Which line is "line 26"? (We can't see your line numbers).

Comment: I can see `file.next()` without any check for `file.hasNext()` - so it is possible that your file iterator just keeps going beyond the end of the iterable data. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator). If you only expect to get a single PDF file, then get that one file _before_ you enter the `for` loop.

Comment: If the existing comment or answer don't solve it for you, can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess. Instead of this:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Guide to Resetting Online Delivery Passwords.pdf");

...

attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
```

You probably need this:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Guide to Resetting Online Delivery Passwords.pdf").next();

...

attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
```

The `getFiles()` gives you an iterator (something similar with an array). The method `.next()` gives you a first (only, actually) element of the iterator.